# problems with tkz-linknodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

doesn't this example work because?

`\LinkNodes`   doesn't work

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[upright]{fourier}
\usepackage{amsmath,tkz-linknodes}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{NodesList}
\begin{displaymath}
\begin{aligned}
3(2a&-5b)&-7a(2a&+3b)&+5(a^2&+3b)& \AddNode[1] \AddNode[2] \AddNode[3] \AddNode[4] \AddNode[5] \AddNode[6] \AddNode[7]\\
6a+&\AddNode[1]\\ 
& -15b&   \AddNode[2]\\
&& -14a^2&   \AddNode[3]\\    
&& &-21ab&   \AddNode[4]\\
&&& &+5a^2&   \AddNode[5]\\
&&&& &+15b&   \AddNode[6]\\
6a&-15b&-14a^2&-21ab&+5a^2&+15b&\AddNode[7]\\   
\end{aligned}
\end{displaymath}

\LinkNodes{$3\cdot 2a$}%    
\LinkNodes{$3\cdot(-5b)$}%
\LinkNodes{$-7a\cdot(2a)$}%
\LinkNodes{$-7a\cdot(3b)$}%
\LinkNodes{$5\cdot(a^2)$}%
\LinkNodes{$5\cdot(3b)$}%

\end{NodesList}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question- at the moment it isn't very clear...

Comment: Seems to work here (I think). Did you compile twice?

Comment: What is your problem exactly ?

Comment: You need to remove amsmath and tikz because tkz-linknodes loads these packages. You need to have a recent xkeyval package and the last thing, tkz-linknodes loads etex.sty. But it will be interesting to know what is going wrong !

Comment: @user13225 Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

You need to compile twice
Update : I added `\AddNode[i]` before the last `&`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[upright]{fourier}
\usepackage{amsmath,tkz-linknodes}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{NodesList}
\begin{displaymath}
\begin{aligned}
3(2a&-5b)&-7a(2a&+3b)&+5(a^2&+3b)&\AddNode[1]\AddNode[2]\AddNode[3]\AddNode[4]\AddNode[5]\AddNode[6]\AddNode[7]\\
6a+&\AddNode[1]\\ 
& -15b\AddNode[2]&\\
&& -14a^2\AddNode[3]&\\    
&& &-21ab\AddNode[4]&\\
&&& &+5a^2\AddNode[5]&\\
&&&& &+15b\AddNode[6]&\\
6a&-15b&-14a^2&-21ab&+5a^2&+15b&\AddNode[7]\\   
\end{aligned}
\end{displaymath}
\tikzset{LabelStyle/.style = {left=0.1cm,pos=.5,text=red,fill=white}}
\LinkNodes[margin=3cm]{$3\cdot 2a$}%    
 \LinkNodes[margin=2cm]{$3\cdot(-5b)$}%
 \LinkNodes[margin=1cm]{$-7a\cdot(2a)$}%
 \LinkNodes[margin=0cm]{$-7a\cdot(3b)$}%
\LinkNodes[margin=-1cm]{$5\cdot(a^2)$}%
 \LinkNodes[margin=-2cm]{$5\cdot(3b)$}%  

\end{NodesList}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another possibility :

```
\begin{NodesList}
\begin{displaymath}
\begin{aligned}
3(2a&-5b)&-7a(2a&+3b)&+5(a^2&+3b)&\AddNode[1]\AddNode[2]\AddNode[3]\AddNode[4]\AddNode[5]\AddNode[6]\AddNode[7]\\
6a+&\AddNode[1]\\ 
& -15b\AddNode[2]&\\
&& -14a^2\AddNode[3]&\\    
&& &-21ab\AddNode[4]&\\
&&& &+5a^2\AddNode[5]&\\
&&&& &+15b\AddNode[6]&\\
6a&-15b&-14a^2&-21ab&+5a^2&+15b&\AddNode[7]\\   
\end{aligned}
\end{displaymath} 
\tikzset{LabelStyle/.style = {pos=0,above,text=red}}
\LinkNodes[margin=1.5cm]{$3\cdot (2a)$}%    
 \LinkNodes[margin=0cm]{$3\cdot(-5b)$}%
 \LinkNodes[margin=-1.5cm]{$-7a\cdot(2a)$}%
 \LinkNodes[margin=-3cm]{$-7a\cdot(3b)$}%
\LinkNodes[margin=-4.5cm]{$5\cdot(a^2)$}%
 \LinkNodes[margin=-6cm]{$5\cdot(3b)$}%  
\end{NodesList}
```

This is a little package to make simple tasks, perhaps I would be more easy for you to use TikZ directly to get exactly what you want.

[image]

Comment: the solution of the problem is this. correct? \tikzset{LabelStyle/.style = {left=0.1cm,pos=.5,text=red,fill=white}}

Comment: @user13225 But what is your problem ? You can't get the same result ?

Comment: @user13225 No the style is only to avoid to mixt texts and lines. The most important is to add correct `margin`.

Comment: the writings in red, they were not correctly lined up, now all ok

Comment: You want align the writings in red with what ? You can modify `pos` but here the different lines don't have the same length.

Comment: merci Altermundus , tu m'as résolu tous mes problèmes